# How to draw a rectangle with iText and Kotlin in an Android App

Tags: android, pdf, kotlin, itext

I found nearly nothing about using iText/iTextG/iTextpdf with Kotlin in Android Studio. There is only this still wrong instruction:
https://developers.itextpdf.com/itextg-android

But if you set a dependency to 5.5.10 instead of 5.5.11 it works. And I was able to create a PDF, writing some Paragraphs of text in it and also place a picture.
But I can't figure out how to draw a rectangle. (And how to place images and text to specific coordinates).

Comment: That documentation is incorrect. Versions 5.5.11, 5.5.12 and 5.5.13 of iTextG are not yet uploaded to Maven Central. This is still in the backlog. Meanwhile use version 5.5.10, which you already did. So only your question about a rectangle remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drawing a rectangle at a specific location on a page can be done by accessing the canvas and performing the drawing operations on it.

```
Document document = new Document(new Rectangle(200, 120));

// step 2
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));

// step 3
document.open();

// step 4
PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

// state 1:
canvas.setRGBColorFill(0xFF, 0x45, 0x00);

// fill a rectangle in state 1
canvas.rectangle(10, 10, 60, 60);
canvas.fill();
canvas.saveState();
```

For more information on adding content at absolute positions, have a look at the documentation: https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext-action-second-edition/chapter-3

Comment: Everything in the iText Documentation - Which is more a collection of questions than a real documentation - is in Java. And some weeks ago I  was not ready yet to adapt the java examples to kotlin.

Lessons Learned:
* It's a bad idea to choose an Android Device as the starting point
* It's much faster to do your first steps, maybe the complete _Design_ in Intellij IDEA
* If you have used the FPDF Library in php over years to create several PDF Docs you'll ask yourself why iText is so complicated
* Therefore a web site could be the better solution, but can't not be sold over the App-Store

Answer (score 1):

Since the things in Kotlin look a little bit different and at first it was hard for me to cope with the differences here is the example in Kotlin.

```
pdfFile = File(docsFolder.absolutePath, "PDF-Document" + kalender.time.toString() + ".pdf")
val output = FileOutputStream(pdfFile!!)
val document = Document()
val writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output)
document.open()
// This will give you a small orange rectangle at the left bottom of the page 
canvas.setRGBColorFill(0xFF, 0x45, 0x00)
canvas.rectangle(10.0, 10.0, 60.0, 60.0)
canvas.fill()
document.close()
```

You can do this and everything else. Drawing Lines, Placing Images and Text. Text can be in Columns and Images can be fitted to table cells. Often I had to read twice in the *Documentation*, @Joris set already the link to.
If you are new to Java/Kotlin, iText AND Android programming, like me, I suggest to forget about Android for the moment. iText also works in IntelliJ IDEA wich gives you a much faster experience. Cause in this case you compile, run and view the generated PDFs directly on your desktop. And in the beginning you'll have to compile and check the result very often. And it is very easy to port the necessary code afterwards.
But doing so you could get a bit upset about the restrictions, you have to deal with inside Android development.

- You have to stay with iText5, there is no iText7 for Android/Java/Kotlin
- You can't access files from anywhere in your filesystem
- To place Images you have place an Instance of their ByteArrayOutputStream instead. Ugly 5 lines of code for every image you want to have in your PDF.

But hey, it works and it's free.